# Android App S3 upload not working. No error

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I am working on building an android app that takes a picture and uploads that to Amazon S3. My code seems to be running fine, in that it is actually running (confirmed via debug breakpoints), however it is not uploading. I get no error messages, and log.d messages that I put into the app do not appear in the logcat.

I am using this amazon tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html#add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage-app

The first time I ran the code, I got an error complaining that `TransferUtility.builder()` didnt have `.s3Client` So I put that in.

Offending code:

```html
private void uploadImage(){
        AWSConfiguration awsConfig =
                new AWSConfiguration(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager()
                .getCredentialsProvider().getCredentials());

        TransferUtility transferUtility =
                TransferUtility.builder()
                        .context(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                        .awsConfiguration(awsConfig)
                        .s3Client(s3Client)
                        .build();

        TransferObserver uploadObserver =
                transferUtility.upload(
                        "sniffer-gps-app/UserDogPhotos/"+userId+photoFile.getName(),
                        photoFile);

        uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
                    //todo something here
                    Log.d("S3", "done");
                    nextFragment();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(
                    int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                Log.d("S3", "ID: "+id+"\r\nBytesCurrent: "+bytesCurrent+"\r\nBytesTotal: "+bytesTotal);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Log.d("S3", ex.toString());
                Integer ID = id;
                Log.d("S3", ID.toString());
            }

        });
    }
```

`photoFile` is a `File` object.

`sniffer-gps-app` is the bucket name

`UserDogPhotos` is a folder in the bucket

Comment: Have you added permission to access network state? something like this:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/S3TransferUtilitySample/AndroidManifest.xml#L38

Comment: I definitely did that. Calls to cognito and dynamoDB are working just fine.

Comment: @Reid does it still uploading when you close the app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service tag in my manifest was outside of my application tag.